# Using log4j in maven project

Tags: java, maven

I have trouble creating the log file

I added in my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>log4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.16</version>
</dependency>
```

then I placed log4j.properies under resources folder

```
# Define the root logger with appender file
log = /home/soumya/log4j
log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, FILE

# Define the file appender
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File=${log}/log.out

# Define the layout for file appender
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.conversionPattern=%m%n
```

Then in My java code I use

```
public class Test
{
static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName());
 public void testLog(){
 logger.info("testing ..!!!");
}
```

But when running I got below error and the log file is not created !!!

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
```

My maven version is  Apache Maven 2.2.1 (rdebian-6) and I am using ecclipse Indigo 
Appreciate any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SLF4j library needs to be included manually in your pom.xml

```
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: what's the jcl-over-slf4j for? If I don't include it, what's the result?

Comment: Some other third party libraries may use JCL (legacy code). You can exclude it. Just that if some third party library is not producing the logs, it may use JLC.

Comment: By including these dependencies the error has gone .But still  no log files are created !!!.What should I do to get the log messages get logged into the file .I tried manually adding log4j in my build path but it also didn't worked :(

Comment: Make sure that the method testLog() is executed (use system.out.println to be sure). Set log4j.appender.FILE.File to use the full path /home/soumya/log4j/log.out The file may be created but in different folder.

Comment: i am sure testLog() is executing I double checked it by using system.out.println . Edited log4j.properties to redirect logs to cosole also by adding log4j.rootLogger =DEBUG, S, R, FILE and use full path in  g4j.appender.FILE . But no hope . Since the logs are not logged into console I might be missing some configurations

Comment: Perhaps, log4j.properties is not read. Try to insert org.apache.log4j.BasicConfigurator.configure(); before logger.info("testing ..!!!"); You can also use org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j.properties"); to force log4j to use the config file.

Comment: OK.I got INFO - Test.Test(62) | testing ..!!! in cosole by adding org.apache.log4j.BasicConfigurator.configure() . But still log files are not created. My log4j.properties is https://gist.github.com/4044029 . Also I got log4j:ERROR Could not read configuration file [log4j.properties].
java.io.FileNotFoundException: log4j.properties (No such file or directory)  when using  org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j.properties");

Comment: @Vito Limandibhrata Thanks for your all your support . Seems its working when give full path while using  org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configure(..../log4j.properties) . Is there any workAround to avoid hardcoding this ??? sorry for keep querying

Comment: The BasicConfigurator/PropertyConfigurator are ways to troubleshoot the log4j issues. I am not sure your maven project configuration. I think the log4j.properties is located in the wrong folder thus it is not automatically picked up by the maven config. Try to put the log4j.properties in different folders i.e classes,WEB-INF,etc

Answer (score 0):

so, I did have like this

import dependency in pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.30</version>
    </dependency>
```

after I import in class.java, have like this

```
 import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
 import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
```

After I did like this create the variable in class and use in your code

```java
final Logger logger = (Logger) LogManager.getLogger(TechLearningv3Application.class);

logger.info("Clientes Encontrados com função findAll():");
```

Print Screen this project here
[image]

Reference - https://www.sentinelone.com/blog/maven-log4j2-project/