# A Maven plugin uses a library which logs with log4j

Tags: java, maven, log4j, maven-plugin

In a Mojo, I get a Logger by using `getLog()`.

Assume I add a dependency to my maven plugin and call a method there. This dependency uses log4j.

Can I redirect the logging to the Maven logging?

EDIT:

I did not specify the version. I need a solution for log4j in version 1.2.17.

Comment: Just use the log4j-slf4j bridge?

Comment: @dan1st Can you give me a hint how you do that?

Comment: Worked for me, this way  - https://stackoverflow.com/a/69916538/8748688

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excluding log4j and then using the dependency

```xml
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.30</version>
    </dependency>
```

seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47082224/10871900), maven supports SLF4J logging.

If you just add the [Log4j to SLF4j adapter](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/log4j-2.2/log4j-to-slf4j/index.html) to the plugin.

You can simply do this in your `pom.xml`:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-to-slf4j</artifactId>
    <version>2.14.0</version>
</dependency>
```

By adding this dependency, log4j will redirect to SLF4j and SLF4j redirects to the maven logging.